# In Ruby on Rails, is there a way to check the order of the rows in a table using RSpec/Capybara for views testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I have a table with numerous rows. These rows are ordered specific to the data within them. I am looking to write tests for the order of the rows in the table. Is there a way to do this using RSpec/Capybara?

Comment: The ordering of rows is the responsibility of the model class. You then test this behavior by creating some test objects(rows) and then testing whether the order of objects returned by the model method is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can try use xpath selectors, for example

```
within(:xpath, "//table/tr[1]/td") do
  page.should have_content('First row content')
end

within(:xpath, "//table/tr[2]/td") do
  page.should have_content('Second row content')
end
```